Qiskit | ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit'', I've tried a lot of attemps to fix this issue and nothing changes
I wanted to run the following part code in jupyter lab:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer
import numpy as np
import qiskit.quantum_info as qi
qc = QuantumCircuit(4,4) # Ponemos 4 qubits y 4 bits
# Aplicamos algunas compuertas
qc.x(0)
qc.y(1)
qc.z(2)
.
.
.

And after I runned the code, I encountered the following error:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import qiskit.quantum_info as qi

ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit' (C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\qiskit\__init__.py)

In order to fix this problem, I've been:

Reinstalled Qiskit, first putting the command: pip uninstall qiskit and then
pip install qiskit in the Anaconda Prompt.
Upgraded Qiskit, with the following command: pip install --upgrade qiskit.
Restarted the Jupyter Lab Kernel.
Checked for conflicting packages, with the following command: pip list. It displayed me a lot of packages I guess, but I coudn´t find the Aer package, Honestly I didn't understand so well this package list.
Searched for documentation abut this Aer package, this gave me to this page: https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/getting_started.html I tried putting the following command in order to install what I understood the Aer package: pip install qiskit-aer.
Followed the given answer for this similar problem as it was reported in: Qiskit | ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit' Doing so, gave me the next error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 from qiskit_aer import QuantumCircuit, Aer
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import qiskit.quantum_info as qi

ImportError: cannot import name 'QuantumCircuit' from 'qiskit_aer' (C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\qiskit_aer\__init__.py)

So at this stage, I don't know how to attack this problem, somebody help me please.

Just do the following,
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_aer import Aer


https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/release-notes/1.0#misc-upgrade-notes
"The object qiskit.Aer has been removed following its deprecation in Qiskit 0.46. You can instead use qiskit_aer.Aer, which is a drop-in replacement."
